# How to move a pygame rect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I run the code below, the pygame rect wont move. It is set to move -7 in the x direction at each left arrow press, but nothing happens. I tried to print the position of the rect, and it seems like it's position is updated once, from the initial position 300, to 293, although there is no movement on screen. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import sys
import pygame

PINK = (255, 102, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.init()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 20)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(750, 550)

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.paddle = pygame.Rect(300, 730,
                                  10,
                                  52)

    def draw_paddle(self):
        # Draw paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, PINK,
                         self.paddle)

    def move_paddle_left(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.paddle.left -= 7
            if self.paddle.left < 0:
                self.paddle.left = 0
            print(self.paddle)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run()
        Paddle()
        # Levels().draw_level_one()
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
            # fps lock, screen fill and method call for input
            clock.tick(60)
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            Paddle().draw_paddle()
            Paddle().move_paddle_left()
            pygame.display.flip()
# Creates instance of the game class, and runs it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game()
    Game().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't get your code to actually draw a paddle, I do notice that you create a new Paddle instance in every iteration of the loop, so the position resets to 300 each time.

Try this instead:

```
def run(self):
    paddle = Paddle()
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        # fps lock, screen fill and method call for input
        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        paddle.draw_paddle()
        paddle.move_paddle_left()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

That way you create a paddle object and then re-use its values in each iteration and it'll keep moving left until it hits 0.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a separate global value file, must've filled in some of the numbers wrong. But thank you so much, of course the error was in the game loop somewhere. This fixed it!

Comment: Glad you got it working! What's it like working with pygame? I've been thinking about giving it a try, but haven't gotten around to it yet.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know haha. I'm learning Object-oriented programming, and this was our first assignment, so both Python and Pygame are new to me. But I do think it's fun, I get annoyed of the indentation sometimes, but it's nice to have so many well working methods available. =)

Comment: Haha, gotcha.  Yes, the whole indentation-as-part-of-the-syntax can be a bit annoying at times, especially when you refactor stuff, but you get used to it.

Good luck with your assignment!